# Highest Temperature Possible from 3 Finite Reservoirs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, heat-engine

I am currently having trouble trying to answer this problem from my textbook:

**Three solid bodies perfectly insulated from their surroundings, each of identical mass m and constant heat capacity $C_P$ are initially at 300 K, 300 K, and 100 K, respectively. Using only reversible heat engines and reversible heat pumps, what is the highest temperature to which any one of these objects may be raised?**

I understand how to go about approaching this problem if it were 2 finite reservoirs but I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about setting up the heat engines/pumps in this situation.

My initial approach to answering this was to make a heat engine operate between one 300K block and the 100K one. Setting the entropy to zero, and skipping a few steps, I end up here:

*Q(low) = mCp(T-100)*

*Q(high) = mCp(300-T)*

*W = Q(high) - Q(low)*

From setting entropy to zero, equating *dQ/T*

*T* = (300*100)^0.5 = 173K

And from this, the work is calculated and transferred as heat to the other block. This would mean T = 354K for the final block, which is incorrect.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Lets work together. do you know the correct answer?

Comment: The problem statement says the maximum temperature, and you are saying the maximum work from the system.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry Chet, I was also having trouble with a similar question asking for the maximum work and originally was going to ask about that

Comment: Also, the correct answer is 400K in the textbook

Comment: If the three solid objects are perfectly insulated, how can you extract heat from them to perform work?

Comment: See https://telescoper.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/yet-another-cute-physics-problem/

Comment: @sammygerbil The description of the problem in the link is not the same as the description given by the OP. The OP statement says each solid body is thermally insulated. As I interpret the link, the three solid bodies are a system insulated from the surroundings. This permits heat exchanges between the bodies and heat engines. Do you agree?

Comment: To avoid confusion, and to be consistent with the link provided by sammy gerbil, I will be suggesting an edit for your consideration.

Comment: @BobD I don't understand your objection. I think the OP statement must be interpreted as meaning that the bodies can exchange heat with each other, either directly or via a heat engine, but there is no heat exchange with the surroundings. It seems to me the same problem. As per your earlier comment, if the bodies are insulated from each other, the problem doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @sammygerbil I just think the phrase "Three solid bodies perfectly insulated from their surroundings" could be interpreted to mean each body is insulated. That's the way it hit me and unless I am a real odd ball I would have to think it could be interpreted that way by others. Although I agree it can't be the case.